# Regarding List<> declaration in C#

Tags: c#, list, generics, textbox

I'm trying to learn List<> in C#. I made a test program that takes the result of three textboxes and inputs it in a multiline textbox, after I put them in a list (to later save the list to file).

Here is my class declaration:

```
public class Film
    {
        public Film (string Num, string Title, string Categ)
        {
            this.Numero = Num;
            this.Titre = Title;
            this.Categorie = Categ;
        }

        public string Numero;
        public string Titre;
        public string Categorie;

    }
```

Now I instantiate the list:

```
List<Film> ListeFilms = new List<Film>();
```

And here is my event:

```
private void btSaveMovie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var MyMovie = new Film(txtNum.Text, txtTitre.Text, cbCateg.Text);

        ListeFilms.Add(MyMovie);
        foreach (Film x in ListeFilms)
        {
            txtAffichage.AppendText(x.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Now when I run, all that is written in the text box is:

```
test_1.Form1+Film
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You have to override the ToString() method in the Film class declaration.Otherwise it returns the type name.

Example:

```
public class Film
{
    public Film(string Num, string Title, string Categ)
    {
         this.Numero = Num;
         this.Titre = Title;
         this.Categorie = Categ;
    }

    public string Numero;
    public string Titre;
    public string Categorie;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Numero.ToString() + " " + Titre.ToString() + " " + Categorie.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to concatenate the three fields into the AppendText function:

```
private void btSaveMovie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var MyMovie = new Film(txtNum.Text, txtTitre.Text, cbCateg.Text);

    ListeFilms.Add(MyMovie);
    foreach (Film x in ListeFilms)
    {
        txtAffichage.AppendText(x.Numero + " - " + x.Titre + "- " + x.Categorie));
    }
}
```